# Explode a String and Check Database for Duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

How can I take a string `business, jquery, css` and `explode` that string and check a mySQL database to see if each one of the single words is already inside a database entry?

Thanks,
Drummer392

Comment: what does your table look like? Come onnn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $conn);

$string  = "business, query, css";
$array = explode(", ", $string);

foreach($array as $str){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName='$str'", $conn);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0)
        //found
    else
        //not found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "business, jquery, css";
$exploded = explode(",", $string);

$result = /* database select query */

foreach ($exploded as $value) {
    // $value contains the value being processed
    // compare $result to $value and do what's needed

}
```

PHP Manual: [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode)

Hope that give you an idea as to what you need to do.

**Edit:** thanks to Chris for the suggestion of doing the database query first

Comment: `","` instead of `", "` returns a variable of `business,jquery,css` if the user should forget to put a comma between the different words.  I have been search all over Google for a way to add a space after a comma only if there isn't a space already.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `explode` function with a ", " delimiter, assigning to a new array variable.

I would improve upon the previous answer, I feel it would be better to use the SELECT query *outside* of the foreach loop. Then you'll avoid executing the same query 3 times.

```
$result = /* database select query */
foreach ($exploded as $value) {
    // compare $result to $value and do what's needed
}
```